# Проблемы с передачей данных сайта с одного языка програмирования на другой

Tags: php, javascript, html, cms

У меня возникла проблема с передачей данных из javascript в php  и из php в html при передаче параметров вместо тех параметров которые я передал выводит 1. Не судите строго.

Код Js

```
 var db ={};

var idProduct ={};
var url={};
var name="<?php echo $name  ?>";
var price={};
var text={};
var image={};
var table={};
var Tab={};
var tableObj = document.createElement('table');
var Table={};
var checkEnter;
var f={};
var Id={};
var j={};
var chek;


function addProduct()
{
//проверка на 0 и проверка первый ли это вызов 
if (idProduct==0)
{
    idProduct++;
}
else
{
   if (chek==true)
   {
     j=idProduct;
   }
   else
   {
       j=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("id"));
   }

    idProduct= j;
    idProduct++;
    table=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tab"))
}
 //считывание введеных данных
   name =document.getElementById("names").value;
text = document.getElementById("texts").value;
price = document.getElementById("prices").value;
url = idProduct + name;// +category
 //проверка на 0
if ((name && text && price) == '') {
    alert('Ваша форма введина неправильна');

    idProduct--;

}
else {
 //уточнение
     checkEnter = confirm('Вы ввели :  ' + name + ' ' + text + ' ' + price + ' ' + url);
    if (checkEnter == false)
    {

        idProduct--;


    }
    else
    {
   // формировка значений таблици
        table += '<tr><td>' + idProduct + '</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>'+ text + '</td><td>'+ price + '</td><td>'+ url+ '</td><td>'+ image + '</td></tr>';

        db = '<tr><td>' + idProduct + '</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>'+ text + '</td><td>'+ price + '</td><td>'+ url+ '</td><td>'+ image + '</td></tr>';
    }
}

Id=JSON.stringify(idProduct);

localStorage["id"]=Id;

f = db.length;


showTable();

 // localStorage.clear() полная очистка таблици
 // location.reload()
}

function showTable()// вывод на экран таблици с введенными данными 
{

Table=JSON.stringify(table);

localStorage["tab"]=Table;

Tab = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tab"));


 tableObj.style.width = '100%';
 var tableHTML = '<tr><td style="width: 20%; padding-bottom: 10px;">index</td><td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">name</td><td style=" padding-bottom: 10px;">text</td><td style=" padding-bottom: 10px;">price</td><td style=" padding-bottom: 10px;">url</td><td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">image</td></tr>';

for (var i = 0; i <1 ; i++)
{
    tableHTML += Tab;
}

tableObj.innerHTML = tableHTML;
document.body.appendChild(tableObj);


 // передача параметров на php 
//  var message = encodeURIComponent(Tab);
location.href="/cms0.0.1/bd.php?name"+name;


 }
```

Код Php

```
    $nam=print $_GET['name'];

require_once ('/cms0.0.1/html/Catalog.html');
```

Код откуда ввожу данные

```
 <body>


 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../script/AddProduct.js">

 </script>

 <form>

Name: <input type='text' id="names"> <br />
text: <input type='text' id="texts"> <br />
price: <input type='text' id="prices"> <br />

 </form>

 <input type="button" value="addproduct" name="addProduct" OnClick="addProduct() ;">

 <input type="button" value="delete product" name="showProduct" OnClick="del() ;">



 </body>
```

Код Html куда я желаю вывести

```
    <body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../script/AddProduct.js "></script>
    <div id="header"><h1>Каталог</h1></div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    <p>    <input type="button" value="" name="showProduct" OnClick=" ">        </p>
  <p>    <input type="button" value="" name="showProduct" OnClick="">         </p>
  <p>    <input type="button" value="" name="showProduct" OnClick="">         </p>
  </div>

 <div id="product">
 <h2>Товары</h2>


<table>

<?php echo  $nam; ?>

</table>

 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Для обмена одного языка с другими используют общепринятые стандарты. JSON (чаще) или XML.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.

Зачем тут print:

```
$nam=print $_GET['name'];
```

Уберите его.

```
<?php echo  $nam; ?>
```

Можно заменить для краткости на:

```
<?= $nam; ?>
```

JS в PHP можно передать с помощью AJAX, обратно можно подставить PHP в HTML и забрать оттуда с помощью JS. Но попробуйте пока просто удалить print.

Comment: Убрал я  print  теперь вместо 1 ничего не выводит , нащот AJAX я знаю , я пока использу синхронный метод передачи , думаете если я сделаю через AJAX всё будет работать как надо ? Нащот "обратно можно подставить PHP в HTML и забрать оттуда с помощью JS"  можно поподробнее.

Comment: "нащот"... ааааааа... мои глаза. X_X